# External URL with Redirection - How can I handle without negative SEO

Tags: seo, google, redirects

This is a WordPress site. There are some post like Best WordPress Themes, Best Articles, etc

Because of some technical reason, we can't just add linked those items.

This is a sample article.

> Best WordPress Themes
>
> 1. `<a href='https://our-site.com/theme/abc'>ABC Theme</a>`
> 2. `<a href='https://our-site.com/theme/efg'>EFGTheme</a>`

What happen is when click the anchor text it goes to `https://our-site.com/theme/abc` and then redirect to `https://external -site.com/any`.

I have set `no-index,no-follow` to `https://our-site.com/theme/abc` page. I have set 301 redirection.

Is above things are correct? Additionally what should I do? Should I add a nofollow to `<a href='https://our-site.com/theme/abc' rel='nofollow' >ABC Theme</a>`

Comment: "Negative SEO" is the practice of using black hat techniques against your competitors.   Or having your competitors get your own website penalized.  An example of it would be purchasing spammy links directed at a competitor.   I don't see what this question has to do with Negative SEO.

Comment: If you mean "without hurting SEO", I'm not sure what you are worried about.  It is very common to have external links redirect on your own site first.   It is often done as a method of tracking what gets clicked.   It shouldn't have any impact on SEO.  You shouldn't need any `noindex` or `nofollow`.

Comment: I also don't understand how your use `301 Permenant` redirects and `noindex, nofollow` on the same page.   The latter is a meta tag and goes in the page head.  There is no page when there is a redirect.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller  I thought "https://our-site.com/theme/abc" consider as page and then it redirect to  the external site. Should I add nofollow as `<a href='https://our-site.com/theme/abc' rel='nofollow' >ABC Theme</a>` ?

Comment: I don't consider redirects to be "pages".  No browser shows them as such.   I don't use nofollow in such cases.  Why do you think it would be a good idea?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I thought even it is redirect Google consider it as a backlink. Most my pages have around 15-20 links like that.....

Comment: Google follows redirects and passes page rank through them but not to them.